# How to filter the email by the content in android?

Tags: android, email

The android default Email is filter by subject, sender or receiver. But how to filter by content? The message body is not saved to database, which is saved to the file in after Android 5.0. Should I put the message body to the database, which do like before Android 5.0? And then filter the content according the keyword? Please give me some advice, Thanks!

```
case BODY:
                final ContentValues dbValues = new ContentValues(values);
                // Prune out the content we don't want in the DB
                dbValues.remove(BodyColumns.HTML_CONTENT);
                dbValues.remove(BodyColumns.TEXT_CONTENT);
                // TODO: move this to the message table
                longId = db.insert(Body.TABLE_NAME, "foo", dbValues);
                resultUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, longId);
                // Write content to the filesystem where appropriate
                // This will look less ugly once the body table is folded into the message table
                // and we can just use longId instead
                if (!values.containsKey(BodyColumns.MESSAGE_KEY)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Cannot insert body without MESSAGE_KEY");
                }
                final long messageId = values.getAsLong(BodyColumns.MESSAGE_KEY);
                // Ensure that no pre-existing body files contaminate the message
                deleteBodyFiles(context, messageId);
                writeBodyFiles(getContext(), messageId, values);
                break;


 public static String buildLocalSearchSelection(Context context, long mailboxId,
            String queryFilter, String queryFactor) {
        StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder();
        selection.append(" (");
        queryFilter = queryFilter.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")
                .replaceAll("%", "\\\\%")
                .replaceAll("_", "\\\\_")
                .replaceAll("'", "''");
        String[] queryFilters = queryFilter.split(" +");

        boolean isAll = false;
        if (queryFactor.contains(SearchParams.SEARCH_FACTOR_ALL)) {
            isAll = true;
        }
        if (queryFactor.contains(SearchParams.SEARCH_FACTOR_SUBJECT) || isAll) {
            selection.append(buildSelectionClause(queryFilters, MessageColumns.SUBJECT));
        }
        if (queryFactor.contains(SearchParams.SEARCH_FACTOR_SENDER) || isAll) {
            selection.append(buildSelectionClause(queryFilters, MessageColumns.FROM_LIST));
        }
        if (queryFactor.contains(SearchParams.SEARCH_FACTOR_RECEIVER) || isAll) {
            selection.append(buildSelectionClause(queryFilters, null));
        }

        selection.delete(selection.length() - " or ".length(), selection.length());
        selection.append(")");
        return selection.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can use the ' MessageColumns.SNIPPET' to filter the email content.